# First-child affect every element inside

Tags: css, css-selectors

[image]

```
ul.idTabs:first-child :before  {
    border-top: none;
}
```

I don't understand why the above style affect every element inside `ul.idTabs`.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Everything else works fine, i just want to set `border-top: none` for the first `li:before` inside `ul.idTabs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul.idTabs li:first-child:before  {
  border-top: none;
}
```

You need to identify the tag of the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
ul.idTabs li:first-child:before {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. you actually targeted all the `ul` that are first childs of some parent..
2. remove the white-space before the `:before`
3. if you don't use the `content` property in the `:before` pseudo class, it wont render.
   this is only if you didn't already assign the `content` property in a more general rule, like `ul.idTabs li` (which you probably did..)

So use:

```
ul.idTabs li:first-child:before {
    content: ""; /*can be empty if you want*/
    border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: 1. yes, i've forgot about meaning of this selector, next time i should think a little bit longer before i ask for help ;) sorry all about this question and thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1):

Since all the above answers gave you the right answer already here something different:

Try to add a class like e.g. "first-item" to the first item. It will then work in any browser, not just the new ones.